# dirPagination doesn't show the data (Angular JS pagination)

Tags: angularjs

I am using dirPagination to paginate data in a table. The very first time I don't see any data. I don't see any errors either.

See my code in action: 
  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3rZoKhnIEnqjUOJNT0iI?p=preview)

```
[Plunker][1]http://plnkr.co/edit/3rZoKhnIEnqjUOJNT0iI?p=preview
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `$scope.currentPage = 1;`

[Fixed plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FzL6pyOuZ91VwlTWjkbe?p=preview)

Comment: Great. thank u. wondering why doesn't the pagination bar doesn't appear even after I change itemsPerPage: 2

Comment: You were missing the template for the pagination directive: dirPagination.tpl.html. I updated the plunker.